# Is it proper to tip the folks who manage the table list?

Tags: etiquette

I know there’s etiquette regarding tipping a dealer. But is it appropriate to tip the folks who manage the player lists for tables? If so, how much?

Answer (score 1):

Appropriate? Sure. Recommended or expected? No.

I have been to about 7 casinos/poker rooms, the table managers never get tipped ever. Only the dealer and the drinks cart people gets tips and it's usually one dollar chip (some people give $5 at higher stake tables).